# Mic,Audio permission in cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have a cordova project use mic and audio. When I use:

```
cordova build android
```

But when i run in my phone it is doesn't work!
**Thanks for help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding 'cordova-plugin-media-capture' will solve your problem!

Please read the documentation here : [Media capture cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html)